# Define testcafe userrole in typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

in Testcafe, I can use the following to define a userrole in javascript:

```
   import { Role,t } from 'testcafe';

export const UserRole:Role=Role('https://example.com/', async (t) => {
        await t
            .typeText('#LoginID', 'user')
            .typeText('#Password', 'Pass1!')
            .click('.btn btn-login');
    },{preserveUrl:true});
```

I have a Typescript project with allowJs is set to false, and when I use the above code in typescript code like

```
fixture ('Check logged user')

    .beforeEach(async t => {
      await t.useRole(UserRole);

});
```

I get

> Error in fixture.beforeEach hook -
>         The "role" argument is expected to be a Role instance, but it was an object.

Comment: I've create a test based on your example and it works properly on my side: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderMoskovkin/f1e0e74540b3e1a59490e2cb9183673d

Could you please check it and find differences with your?